# Adding a clear button to the first option in a dropdown, options are controlled by a javascript loop

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make the first "option" in a dropdown a clear button. Basically, the markup is a simple select component with three options, controlled by javascript written by a previous developer at work. So far, I'm able to inject the button html from outside the loop using a querySelector to the first option, but there I can't get rid of the checkmark in only the first option. I've spent many hours on this and am close but frustrated :/. Any insight is appreciated. Here is a link to a pen with the live sample:
https://codepen.io/sfilippone/pen/rNmEKXd

Markup:

```
 <select multiple name="option">
          <option value="clear">Clear</option>
          <option value="web">Web</option>
          <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
 </select>
```

Javascript:

```
function dropdowns() {
  let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".c-dropdown");
  let checkboxHTML =
    '<label class="c-checkbox"><input type="checkbox"><span class="c-checkmark"></span></label>';
  let clearButtonHTML =
    '<div class="dropdown-clear-option"><span class="icon-24-refresh-mono clear-icon"></span>Clear</div>';

  dropdowns.forEach(function (dropdown) {
    (function (dropdown) {
      let multiple = dropdown.querySelector("select").hasAttribute("multiple");
      let checkmark = multiple ? checkboxHTML : "";

      let clearAll = dropdown.querySelector("select").hasAttribute("clearbtn");

      if (multiple) {
        dropdown.classList.add("c-dropdown--multiple");
      }

      let container = document.createElement("div");
      container.setAttribute("tabindex", "0");
      container.innerHTML = dropdown.classList.contains(
        "c-dropdown--inline-label"
      )
        ? dropdown.querySelector("label").innerHTML
        : "Order Source";
      container.classList.add("c-dropdown__container");
      dropdown.appendChild(container);

      let optionsContainer = document.createElement("div");
      optionsContainer.classList.add("c-dropdown__options-container");
      dropdown.appendChild(optionsContainer);

      let options = dropdown.querySelectorAll("select option");
      let labelText = dropdown.querySelector("label").innerHTML;

      //***** Setting up Clear button
      let firstOption = dropdown.querySelector("select option[value=clear]");
      firstOption.innerHTML = clearButtonHTML;

      for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        // ****** Loop adds innerHTML
        let optionDiv = document.createElement("div");
        optionDiv.innerHTML = checkmark + options[i].innerHTML;
        optionDiv.classList.add("c-dropdown__option");
        optionsContainer.appendChild(optionDiv);

        optionDiv.onclick = function (e) {
          if (!multiple) {
            dropdown.querySelector("select").selectedIndex = i;

            for (let j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
              if (i === j) options[j].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
              else options[j].removeAttribute("selected");
            }

            container.innerHTML = options[i].innerHTML;
            container.classList.toggle("c-dropdown--active");
            optionsContainer.classList.toggle("c-dropdown--active");
            container.classList.add("c-dropdown__container--has-value");
          } else {
            let target = e.target.tagName;
            let checkbox;
            switch (target) {
              case "DIV":
                //Option text
                checkbox = e.target.querySelector("input");
                break;
              case "SPAN":
                checkbox = e.target.parentElement.querySelector("input");
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                break;
              case "INPUT":
                //Checkbox
                checkbox = e.target;
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                break;
            }

            if (options[i].hasAttribute("selected")) {
              options[i].removeAttribute("selected");
              checkbox.checked = false;
            } else {
              options[i].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
              checkbox.checked = true;
            }

            let selected = [];

            for (let j = 0; j < options.length; j++) {
              if (options[j].hasAttribute("selected")) {
                selected.push(options[j].innerHTML);
              }
            }

            container.innerHTML = "Select";

            let maxLength = Math.floor(container.clientWidth / 14);
            let string = "";

            for (let k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {
              string += selected[k];
              if (k < selected.length - 1) {
                string += ", ";
              }
            }

            if (string.length > maxLength) {
              string = selected[0] + ", +" + (selected.length - 1);
            }

            if (selected.length === 0) {
              container.innerHTML = labelText;
              container.classList.remove("c-dropdown__container--has-value");
            } else {
              container.innerHTML = string;
              container.classList.add("c-dropdown__container--has-value");
            }
          }
          dropdown.querySelector("select").dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
        };
      }

      container.onclick = function (e) {
        container.classList.toggle("c-dropdown--active");
        optionsContainer.classList.toggle("c-dropdown--active");
        e.stopPropagation();
      };
    })(dropdown);
  });

  document.onclick = function () {
    document
      .querySelectorAll(
        ".c-dropdown__container, .c-dropdown__options-container"
      )
      .forEach(function (element) {
        element.classList.remove("c-dropdown--active");
      });
  };
}

dropdowns();
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code sets the selected option to a non-existent option when the option with value "clear" is clicked.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('select');
select.onclick = function() {
    if (select.value == 'clear') {
        select.selectedIndex = -1;
    }
};
```

```html
<select multiple name="option" id="select">
    <option value="clear">Clear</option>
    <option value="web">Web</option>
    <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, George, this solves part of the problem. I'm still trying to remove the checkbox from the first option.

Comment: Can you update your code example with your updated code? I'll take a look.

Comment: Hi George, full code is at the pen in the link: https://codepen.io/sfilippone/pen/rNmEKXd

The dropdown is in the header of the table in the live example. Thank you.

Comment: I am not noticing a difference in the interface between your earlier example and this. What part of the problem was solved and what part remains?